# How to check matching percentage of two string lists?

Tags: python, string, list, match

I am a beginner at python. Here I had a problem with comparing two lists. My first problem is the list should not be compared exactly. But It should be compared about **70%** matching with other list and return true if exist. **contains**() method doesn't help in this case. Here is my list:

```
TotalTags = ["citrus", "orange", "vitamin-C", "sweet", "yellow", "vitamin-A"] #etc
LikedTags = ["citrus", "orange", "vitamin-D"]
```

Comment: What is the target list that yields 70%?

Comment: @Lazyer the target list is the totaltags and if it has all the elements in likedtags then it will be 100% but  70% elements is enough for me.

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you walk us through how you get that number?

Comment: @okayatcp no thanks ,But had already got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fuzzywuzzy library in Sahil Desai's answer looks really simple.

Here is an idea with basic functions.

```
TotalTags = ["citrus", "orange", "vitamin-C", "sweet", "yellow", "vitamin-A"] #etc
LikedTags = ["citrus", "orange", "vitamin-C", "sweet", "yellow"]

print(len(set(TotalTags).intersection(set(LikedTags))) / len(TotalTags))  # 0.8333333
print(sum([True for x in TotalTags if x in LikedTags]) / len(TotalTags))  # 0.8333333
```

Comment: Your idea is the best because I don't need Third-party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

you can utilizes fuzzywuzzy python library

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

TotalTags = ["citrus", "orange", "vitamin-C", "sweet", "yellow", "vitamin-A"] #etc
LikedTags = ["citrus", "orange", "vitamin-D"]


per = fuzz.ratio(TotalTags,LikedTags)
per

 65
```

This method directly match the characters of the two list if you want to just match the items then you can used Jaccard similarity method.

Comment: is that inbuilt

Comment: you have to install the library from pip

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) and find similarity between each two word from two list like below: *(Output only shows two words that have similarity > 70%)*

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
TotalTags = ["citrus", "orange", "vitamin-C", "sweet", "yellow", "vitamin-A"]
LikedTags = ["citrus", "orange", "vitamin-D"]
for a in LikedTags:
    for b in TotalTags:
        sim = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
        if sim > 0.7:
            print(f'similarity of {a} & {b} : {sim}')
```

Output:

```
similarity of citrus & citrus : 1.0
similarity of orange & orange : 1.0
similarity of vitamin-D & vitamin-C : 0.8888888888888888
similarity of vitamin-D & vitamin-A : 0.8888888888888888
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't want third-party libraries.

Comment: no thanks I had already got it.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do something like this with the builtin [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#module-collections) module

```
import collections
TotalTags = ["citrus", "orange", "vitamin-C", "sweet", "yellow", "vitamin-A"] #etc
LikedTags = ["citrus", "orange", "vitamin-C", "sweet", "yellow"]
c = collections.Counter(TotalTags)
c.subtract(LinkedTags)
print(1-c.total()/len(TotalTags))
```

output:

```
0.8333333333333334
```